# Getting a 200 OK instead of a 302 Found on cURL

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL over PHP to access an ASPX website. On my browser it shows that upon request I get a `302 Found` (which is redirecting actually to another site), and immediately another request to the redirect page.

On my cURL I always get the `200 OK`, which is ironically wrong , as the next page I am accessing (immitating the redirect) returns a `500`, prehaps something was done wrong in the previous page.

as a test I tried to access my own website on which I am redirecting the page. I also got a `200 OK` on the `curl_getinfo($curl);` but the contents of the returned page showed specifically that the header was `HTTP/1.1 302 Found`
one more weird thing is that the `curl_getinfo($curl);` returns a 200 OK all the time, even when I access my own website when I actually know I am redirecting.

Any ideas why I get a 200 OK instead of a 302 on my `curl_getinfo`?

Thanks!

Comment: have you set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);` inside your curl calls...

Comment: It is. So it makes curl actually return me the contents of the redirected page instead ?

Comment: As the name suggests, it follows location redirections.

Comment: What the hell is can I invite you to chat :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION](http://docs.php.net/function.curl-setopt) answers:
You can also set the CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION option and take a look at the redirect(s), e.g. via

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'read_header');
...
curl_exec($ch);
...
function read_header($curl, $header) {
  echo $header;
  return strlen($header);
}
```

With CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION enabled you should get an output like

```
HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2012 11:26:37 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://www.spiegel.de/
Content-Length: 230
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-Cache: MISS from lnxp-3968.srv.mediaways.net
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from lnxp-3968.srv.mediaways.net:91
Via: 1.0 lnxp-3968.srv.mediaways.net (squid/3.1.4)
Connection: close

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2012 11:25:38 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.0.3SP1 (build: CVSTag=JBoss_4_0_3_SP1 date=200510231054)/Tomcat-5.5
Cache-Control: max-age=120
Expires: Fri, 20 Apr 2012 11:27:38 GMT
X-Host: lnxp-2885
X-Robots-Tag: index, follow, noarchive
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 161305
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Age: 59
X-Cache: HIT from lnxp-3954.srv.mediaways.net
X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from lnxp-3954.srv.mediaways.net:90
Via: 1.1 www.spiegel.de, 1.0 lnxp-3954.srv.mediaways.net (squid/3.1.4)
Connection: close
```

which in this case shows that a request for http://spiegel.de is redirected to http://www.spiegel.de

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is on.